# Trying to add a point to a SRSS 2005 chart

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have created a line chart using Reporting Services that charts the number of accidents per month.  That works great.

The problem is that now I need to add a marker to the chart that indicates when new safety procedures were put in place.  This will just be a single date that is in a separate table.  Ideally, it would show up as a line on the date axis showing the date the the new procedures were implemented.  Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I may have oversimplified this.  There is a chart like this for each of our locations, so the conversion date will be different for each.  Therefore, I can't just add it in as a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new value element to your chart. Set it's value expression to the date/value that you want. This will create a horizontal line.

edit: Then create a formula / modify your query to get the desired value. The process shouldn't change.